Override Analytics/Order Woocommerce Attribution?
The main objective is to add a list after those infos (net sale, clients, orders, products, items sold) with the "attribution" and the sum ($) of each attribution.
I must take the Attribution Column and put it below the list (image 1)
I tried to change the data from class-wc-report-sales-by-date.php by adding a function on functions.php  but nothing occurred. I'm mostly certain I'm doing the wrong way, but I'm kinda lost.
List where I need to put new List with attribution
The attribution column in table
$this->report_data->total_coupons = number_format(array_sum(wp_list_pluck($this->report_data->coupons, 'discount_amount')), 2, '.', '');

And on Functions.php:
function custom_admin_report_data($report_data)
{
    // HERE you make your calculations and changes
    // New amout to set (example)
    $new_calculated_amount = 100;
    //number_format(array_sum(wp_list_pluck($this->report_data->coupons, 'discount_amount')), 2, '.', '');
    // Set the new amounts for "total_coupons" key
    $report_data->total_coupons = $new_calculated_amount;

    // Raw data output just for testing, to get the keys and the structure of the data
    // to be removed
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($report_data);
    echo '</pre>';

    // Return the changed data object
    return $report_data;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_admin_report_data', 'custom_admin_report_data', 10, 1);


try to change the filter from woocommerce_admin_report_data to woocommerce_reports_get_order_report_data
add_filter('woocommerce_reports_get_order_report_data', 'custom_modify_sales_by_date_report_data', 10, 1);

function custom_modify_sales_by_date_report_data($data) {
    // Check if we are in the sales by date report context
    if (isset($data->total_coupons)) {
       $new_calculated_amount = 100;
        $data->total_coupons = $new_calculated_amount;
    }

    return $data;
}

 


I think I put incorrectly my objective, there is a list under the table like:
" 3,627 orders  1,709 clients 263 products 6,300 items sold 1 coupon 5,350 net sales. "
I wanted to put under this list the "Attributions"/Origins I have for each Order.
